# chip-seq alignment with multimach reads

Tags: bioinformatics

I have two Chip-Seq samples and the first step I want to perform it so align them to the reference following two strategies:

1. remove all the reads that matches to more than one site
2. for the reads that matches to more than one site, bind them to a random site

As I understood, the (2) can be done by using the option `-a` from `bowtie2`. Am I right? Some suggestion of how to follow with (1)?

Comment: IIRC correctly there's a flag in the SAM format that tells you if the read could be mapped uniquely

Comment: For questions regarding bioinformatics-specific software, you'll probably get a better answer on https://www.biostars.org/